# Raku .hyper() and .race() example not working

Tags: raku

The following example code should accelerate the execution of a Raku program:

```
for (1..4).race()  {
    say "Doing $_";
    sleep 1;
 }
 say now - INIT now;
```

I remember, that it worked some time ago, but now I always end up with 4 seconds runtime. Also using .race() or adding parameters doesn't change anything. What does I have to do, to run 2 processes at the same time?

Comment: It might be a regression. Did you try to use commitable to run it in different versions?

Comment: The default batch size is 64.  So if you run your program like that, it will never have enough entries to fill a single batch.

Having said that, it looks like it is showing the same behaviour with `.race(batch => 1)`.  Investigating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`race`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterable#method_race) with the named argument `batch` and the statement prefix [`race`](https://docs.raku.org/language/statement-prefixes#index-entry-race_(statement_prefix)-race).

```
say race for (1..4).race(batch=>1)  {
    say "Doing $_";
    sleep 1.rand;$_
}
say now - INIT now;
```

Comment: I also used the named arguments for my tests (batch => 1, degree => 2) but this was not enough. The difference comes from the prefix "race" (in front of the "for"). Thanks!!